# how to redirect a URL according to get variables in URL

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

I am trying to change my website URL according to get variables so that I can increase the security of my website.

For example I want to change my address, this is my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /category.php?cat_id=$1&mode=full&start=$1
```

And my website URL is:

```
http://joinexam.in/category.php?cat_id=17&mode=full&start=36
```

I want to convert this URL to:

```
http://joinexam.in/category/1736
```

- where cat_id = 17
- and start= 36

So it will become `1736` after the `category.php` page, I am trying to do it by using .htaccess file.

Here I want to take both `cat_id` and `start` as get variable, then according to these get variables, I want to change the URL of my website.

Can anyone explain the correct way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

**.htaccess**

This forwards every URL to index.php.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php
```

**PHP**

Get the "original" URL inside index.php:

```
// this gives you the full url
$request_uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 

// split the path by '/'
$params     = split("/", $request_uri);
```

Then you might route based on these $params.
As a good and fast router lib i suggest: https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute
By using this, you don't have to mess around with htaccess regexp stuff and can keep things at the PHP level :)